# C# System.IO.File.WriteAllText with "FOR XML query" not writing all data to file?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following code in which I'm writing the result of a query to xml and then to a file. Is there some sort of limitation on how much File.WriteAlltext will output?  I can't figure out why I'm missing data in the file. Currently it doesn't seem to be able to be larger than 2kb. Thanks!

```
string query = "SELECT [GUID],Field1,Field2 FROM [Test].[dbo].[Test] WHERE LASTMODIFIED >= '20151230' FOR XML PATH('Test'), ROOT('Tests')";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=mydatabase ;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=user;Password=pass"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();


            string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            con.Close();

            File.WriteAllText(@"E:\Test\file.txt", result);
```

Comment: `WriteAllText` doesn't have a limit (in this sense).  Have you added a breakpoint on the line `con.Close();` to check if `result` contains the value you expect?

Comment: Good point.  Just checked and it seems the query data is being cut short for some reason.  The same query however returns all data when run in SSMS.

Comment: How much data is being returned on the query?  Is it hitting the SQL limit for a single string?

Comment: I'm not sure what the maximum length is,  but I wouldn't think that it is hitting it.  I did result.Length; and it returned 2033.  The text file is only 2kb  as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I should have been using the ExecuteXmlReader method to read "FOR XML" queries. The data otherwise will be truncated at 2033 as in my scenario.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310378

Updated code starting with con.Open();

```
con.Open();

            var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            con.Close();

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(result);


            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"E:\Test\test.txt", null);
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            doc.Save(writer);
```